# preg_match (I can't do regex)

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

The company I work for have asked me to give them the ability to place a modal box on the web page from the CMS, but do not want to type HTML. As I cannot for the life of me understand regex I can't get it.

The layout of the code they should type is this:

```
++modal++
Some paragraph text.

Another paragraph.
++endmodal++
```

The paragraphs are already converted by markdown into `<p>paragraph</p>`.

So really the match has to be `++modal++ any number of A-Za-z0-9any symbol excluding + ++endmodal++` then replaced with HTML.

I'm not sure it `preg_match` or `preg_replace` should be used.

I got this far:

```
$string = '++modal++<p>Hello</p>++endmodal++';
$pattern = '/\+\+modal\+\+/';

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: A to be a bit more clear, I wish to replace the ++modal++ and ++endmodal++ with HTML and leave the middle bit as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really think you need a RegEx here as your delimiters remain always the same and always on the same position of the string. Regular expressions are also expensive on resources and as a third counter argument you said you're not fit with them.
So why not use a simple replacement or string trimming if it comes to that.

```
$search = array('++modal++', '++endmodal++');
$replacement = array('<tag>', '</tag>');
$str = '++modal++<p>Hello</p>++endmodal++';

$result = str_replace($search, $replacement, $str);
```

Where, of course, `'<tag>'` and `'</tag>'` are just example placeholders for your replacement.

This is what the manual for [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) says:

```
If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions),
you should always use this function instead of preg_replace().
```

Comment: Hmm I didn't think of that. Seems much simpler. And it works wonderfully. Thank you sir. I feel stupid now.

Comment: No worries, it's normal to overthink sometimes ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should get your desired content using:

```
preg_match('/\+\+modal\+\+([^\+]+)\+\+endmodal\+\+/', $string, $matches)

$matches[1] = '<p>Hello</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to re-invent the wheel here. You're trying to write a simple template system here, but there are dozens of templating tools for PHP that you could use, ranging from big and complex like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) and [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) to really simple ones that aren't much more than you're trying to write.

I haven't used them all, so rather than recommend one I'll point you to [a list of template engines you could try](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/19-promising-php-template-engines/). You'll probably find more with a quick bit of googling.

If you do insist on writing your own, it's important to consider security. If you're outputting anything that contains data entered by your users, you must make sure all your output is properly escaped and sanitised for display on a web page; there a numerous common hacks that can take advantage of an insecure templating system to completely compromise a site.

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter that already takes care of all that for me on input. But yeah it is definitely something to keep in mind. I don't want to write an entire templating system, it is just this small thing that needed to be changed. 

I could've left it with HTML and said tough, but I don't think they would've been too happy.

Comment: I never understood why people think that `++blah++` is somehow easier to read than `<blah>`.... but I've had the same conversations myself. It seems to be quite a common opinion.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$string = '++modal++<p>Hello</p>++endmodal++';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = "/\+\+modal\+\+/"; // put '\' just before +
$patterns[1] = "/\+\+endmodal\+\+/";

$replacements = array();

$replacements[1] = '<html>';
$replacements[0] = '</html>';

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
?>
```

Very similar to [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#example-4546)